# Debugging in matlab

Tags: matlab, debugging, singular

I want to know which line caused Matrix Close to Singular Warning in matlab. How can I do it?
Right now I have lots of places where I try to invert the matrix. I want to know at which particular place it was raised.

Comment: Please post the code and the output you get when you try to run it.  Thanks!

Comment: As above comment: find the smallest, most simple bit of code that borks and then post

Comment: @user34790 - How did my answer work for you?  It should show you right where the warning pops up and it will give you an opportunity to inspect the inputs that are responsible.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the debugger stop automatically with a warning by typing the following command before running,

```
dbstop if warning
```

For example, I created a file called `dbstopIfWarningTest.m` with just one line, `inv(zeros(3))`, and when I run the function, it stops on that line:

```
>> dbstopIfWarningTest
Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision. 
> In dbstopIfWarningTest at 1 

Warning from dbstopIfWarningTest at 1
inv(zeros(3))
K>>
```

Then you can look to see what the inputs are that are causing the warning.